# How to read an arbitrary field from an object's binary without fully deserializing it?

Tags: c#, serialization, binary

**I need a binary serializer**, which is a bit special in that **it can read arbitrary fields from the binary data of an object without full deserialization**.
As far as I know, only one qualified serializer is currently found.
[Apache Ignite](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller) : It enables you to read an arbitrary field from an object's serialized form without full object deserialization.
I wonder if there are any other qualified serializers (any programming language) besides **Apache Ignite**?
**If I implement it myself, how do I name the serializer from a functional point of view?**

---

**supplement :**
Most serializers are originally designed for network communication, and their main task is to completely serialize and deserialize an entity.
If there is a component that needs to serialize a large object to disk, considering that in some cases, the component only needs to read a certain field in the object during deserialization. Considering the performance impact, a serializer cannot be achieved by fully deserializing the object and then reading a field. The marshalled binary data should have metadata information.
The serializer I need can directly route to the offset of a certain field by reading the metadata information. In this way, this is what **bjson, MessagePack, and protobuf** cannot be good at

Comment: Many serializers (binary or otherwise) have a raw reader API; protobuf has a "field-set" concept; what exactly would your usage look like in an ideal case?

Comment: @Marc Gravell  Hello, because the reply length is limited, I will add my scene description to my question

Comment: what sort of payload sizes are you taking about here? It matters.

Comment: @Marc Gravell There is no limit to the payload, so it cannot be ignored and parsed through [SkipObj] like traditional serializers, because when there are too many fields, this overhead will become very large

Comment: @Marc Gravell If you develop a serializer, the serialized binary data header contains the metadata of each field, and you can locate the offset of each field through the API. How do you name this serializer?

Comment: that is making a lot of assumptions, and for the record I have developed serializers (plural). Honestly, though, I wonder whether a file-based database might be a better fit for your purpose.

Comment: @Marc Gravell In fact, based on my assumption above, I have developed  a serializer like this, but I don't know how to name it. Do you have any good suggestions?

Comment: There are two hard problems in programming; cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221846/discussion-between-zeng-and-marc-gravell).